# Creating a Vector of std::thread causes runtime error in g++ but runs fine in Visual Studio?? Why?

Tags: c++, g++, stdthread

I have been stumped for days and my mind has given up on it trying to understand. Looked online for reason/ solution but couldn't find any... not sure why??!??

Using g++ version 11.1.0

[image]

Version of VS I am using

[image]

Here is the code. Thanks!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

const int PRODUCER_COUNT = 10;

void Producer(int index) {
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::thread> producers_and_consumers;

    int i = 0;

    // Create producers
    for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_COUNT; ++i)
        producers_and_consumers.push_back(std::thread(Producer, i));


    // Wait for consumers and producers to finish
    for (auto& t : producers_and_consumers)
        t.join();


    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `PRODUCER_COUNT`?  Is this the actual code that crashes or is it stripped down?

Comment: What's the compiler flag? Have you added `-pthread` ?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - Do I need to add compiler flag as I am using g++ with version 11 which supports it . Well I even tried with -std=c++20 and still I am getting runtime error. Also I am using std::thread and not pthread, so I assume I don't need to include pthread compiler flag.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It is the stripdown code.... I I do have it initialized. Like I said the code works in VS

Comment: Try with this flag `-lpthread`,  to use `std::thread` in g++ we need it, it's a must-have dependency.

Comment: *"It is the stripdown code"* - does this *exact* code produce the *exact* error your stating? And out of curiosity, Mingw? Not surprisingly, I cannot reproduce this issue on Ubuntu with native g++11

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, you can set any value to PRODUCER_COUNT and include the required headers. I installed g++ 11.07 (Test) using Cygwin.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin still get the same error even if I add-lpthread :(

Comment: Please add a [mre].  We need enough code to replicate the crash on our machines.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have edited the code with a minimal producible example. Thanks!!!

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin well that depends if you have a pthread version of g++ or not -- there are various different g++ ports for Windows, some use Win32 threads

Comment: Also added g++ version with screenshot and VS version I am using.

Comment: The error message indicates some "dll hell" -- you're mixing one compiler version with a different version runtime DLLs .  One way to avoid this would be to do a fully static build

Comment: I suggest using wsl to avoid such kinds of problems.

Comment: @M.M Oh ok... now I get it thanks!! But, how can I g++ use a different DLL to run it?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I was looking into it ... WSL seems like a whole new can of worms... might as install ubuntu on VM or something..

Comment: make sure you don't have different versions of g++ runtime DLLs on your system path; and if you are not doing a static build, then deploy the right DLLs with your executable

Comment: @M.M I have different version of g++ DLL on my system?? I will remove the cygwin directory and try and install g++ again. Thanks!